# Github Actions ./config give on token with

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, github-actions, config, workflow

i want to use Github Actions for deploying my react nodejs code to nginx. For this i've run those commands:

```
curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz -L 
https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.301.1/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
yes "" | ./config.sh --url https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy-aws --token AVYXWHVAXX2TB4J63XBJCIDDYB6TA
sudo ./svc.sh install
sudo ./svc.sh start
```

Those are the essential commands. I want, that i can use this token also for other ec2 instances: `AVYXWHVAXX2TB4J63XBJCIDDYB6TA`. I've set a repository secret with a value, but it doesn't work. I want to run this commands by terraform and cloud-init, thats why i can't just copy the token from the online github page. So does anyone know how i can set a fix token, so i can create multiple instances with terraform and cloud-init. Isn't it enough if the token is given in the workflow file?

workflow file:

```
**# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: self-hosted

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [16.x]
    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    cache: 'npm'
    token: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_TOKEN }}
- run: npm ci
- run: npm run build --if-present
```

After this command `yes "" | ./config.sh --url https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy-aws --token AVYXWHVAXX2TB4J63XBJCIDDYB6TA` this happens:

```
Http response code: NotFound from 'POST https://api.github.com/actions/runner-registration' (Request Id: 9530:5EB4:1A2D16B:35B9403:63D2A781)
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

Comment: Just to make sure, that's not a real token, is it?